# Dealing with multi Realms for multi account on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am currently dealing with a Realm problem.

Here is the situation :

My app saves messages locally (in Realm). So you can talk to your friend, and it saves the messages in the database. Currently, if you log out of your account and log in an other account you will find messages that don't belong to your account, so we decided to add a multi-account strategy.

Solution :

We create one .realm file for each logged in users, named like this :

> "USER-\(userId).realm"

UserManagement.swift :

```
func userDidLogIn() {
    guard let currentAccount = currentAccount else { return }

    var config = Realm.Configuration()

    // Use the default directory, but replace the filename with the username
    config.fileURL = config.fileURL!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("USER-\(currentAccount.id_p).realm")

    print("Realm Configuration URL : Changed TO => \(config.fileURL)")

    realmDefaultConfiguration = config
    // Set this as the configuration used for the default Realm
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
}
```

RealmMessageService.swift :

```
func saveMessageToRealm(message: RealmMessage, to convo: RealmConversation) {
    print("Realm Configuration URL : \(self.realm.configuration.fileURL?.absoluteString ?? "NO URL FILE FOUND")")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        try! self.realm.write {
            convo.messages.append(message)
        }
    }
}
```

It's working perfectly, the messages that belong to the USER-15 are only displayed to the user 15, you got it.

But, at one point, Realm is not using the right file.

Steps to reproduce the bug :

1) Log in to the account 15
2) Talk to a friend .
3) Log out .

Console output :

> Realm Configuration URL : Changed TO => "USER-15.realm"
>
> Realm Configuration URL : "USER-15.realm"
>
> Realm Configuration URL : "USER-15.realm"

4) Log in to account 31 .
5) Talk to your friend .

**CRASH**

Console output :

> Realm Configuration URL : Changed TO => "USER-31.realm"
>
> Realm Configuration URL : "USER-15.realm"
>
> Realm Configuration URL : "USER-15.realm"

So, I hope you understood the problem .. I think this may be a sort of "cache issue".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You can just create many-to-one instead of creating new Realm? Each message will have an `user` property

Comment: It was a solution at the beginning but, it's been too complicated to handle the relations, the permissions ... The One file / User is the best solution and the most powerful for our usage.